# c++ : looking away to implement this scenario

Tags: c++, function, multithreading

I'm looking to find how to implement this scenario:
I have logic code that is inside function,
now I like to be able to execute this function in a separate thread.
now what I have is a raw implementation of this ..
I simple Init the Thread that in its Start/Run method I keep the function logic .
how can I make it more generic? so I could send the function (maybe function pointer)
to generic thread factory/pool? 
in c++

Comment: You might want to break this into sentences and paragraphs. This is unreadable.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add a few linebreaks to your question? I find it very difficult to read/understand

Comment: well i try to .. but with no lock .. what is the trick here ?

Comment: What threading library are you using? You are describing how boost::thread (or the upcoming std::thread) library work. When dealing with thread questions, the concrete library that you are using matters a lot, since threads are yet unstandardized in c++.

Comment: @user63898: The trick is __very simple:__ You just need to read the hints about editing that appear to the right of the edit window and follow their lead. If that is too complicated, you could always _look at all your other questions which were edited by helpful people_ to see what they did to achieve what you apparently can not. And, __no__, I'm not going to edit this question for you. __Having asked 136 questions should be enough to have learned the basics of asking a question here.__

Answer (score 3):

This is the command pattern. The usual solution is to bundle the logic into a function object:

```
class DoSomething {
public:
    // Constructor accepts and stores parameters to be used
    // by the code itself.
    DoSomething(int i, std::string s)
        : i_(i), s_(s) { }

    void operator()() {
        // Do the work here, using i_ and s_
    }

 private:
    int i_;
    std::string s_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at boost::thread and boost::bind as these will become the std::tr1::thread and std::tr1::bind.

boost::thread is a small object, receiving a **functor** pointer with no return value and no arguments.

That means either a pointer to a function declared as `void (*function)(void);` or a struct/class implementing `void operator()()`.

If you also use boost::bind, you can adapt basically any functor to be called as `void (*functor)(void)`.

That's as flexible as you can get (as you can transform any function or function-like object to be called with no parameters, then launch it in it's own thread).